# Triggers - Preciso de ajuda para resolver a questão abaixo

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tenho a seguinte situação :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As tabelas descritas acima são repectivamente `ger_usuario`, `ger_mensagem` e `ger_destinos`.

Sendo, o campo `proprietario` (`ger_mensagem`) uma FOREIGN KEY fazendo referência à tabela `ger_usuario`.

Sendo, o campo `id_destino` (`ger_mensagem`) uma FOREIGN KEY fazendo referência à tabela `ger_destinos`.

Preciso de uma Trigger que busque o valor do último `id_destino` (`ger_destinos`) para só depois adicioná-lo à tabela `ger_mensagem`. No caso o `proprietario` vai ser comparado via código.

Fiz essa Trigger :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER manut_destino BEFORE INSERT
ON ger_mensagem 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    DECLARE var_dest INT;


    INSERT INTO ger_destinos VALUES ('','',0);

    SELECT id_destino INTO var_dest FROM ger_destinos ORDER BY id_destino DESC; 

    INSERT INTO ger_mensagem VALUES ('','NEW.assunto','NEW.cat','NEW.rec','NEW.data_cria',
                                         'NEW.del','NEW.del_nom','NEW.del_data',1,var_dest);    

end $$
```

Porém ela apresenta o seguinte erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá sua trigger possui alguns erros, primeiramente, pegue o valor do dest na variável usando o `LIMIT 1`, porque caso exista mais de um registro ele vai tentar atribuir a variavel e vai dar erro.
Segundo você não pode `ALTERAR/INSERIR` Registros na mesma tabela da trigger se não ela vai entrar em um laço de repetição infinito, pense que sempre que você for inserir vai fazer uma ação e assim consecutivamente, então vamos lá.
para inserir o registro basta você atribuir o valor dessa maneira `SET NEW.id_destino = var_dest;` e ele irá inserir o valor no registro que você está inserindo, sua trigger ficará assim então:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER manut_destino BEFORE INSERT
ON ger_mensagem 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    DECLARE var_dest INT;

    INSERT INTO ger_destinos VALUES (NULL,0,0);

    SELECT 
            id_destino INTO var_dest 
        FROM ger_destinos 
        ORDER BY id_destino DESC LIMIT 1; 

    SET NEW.id_destino = var_dest;

end $$
```